# Include a link of node with text in block body

Tags: 8, blocks, configuration

How can I include a link to a particular page in the block body? I don't want to create a custom block.

Answer (score 0):

check the text format in  block body  changes it to full html then include link . it will working fine  check this screenshot http://prntscr.com/bq9okc

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Just use create a link from the editor, and give the node ID of the node.